# How to share access for local server instance for the remote web service(google doc)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, asp.net-web-api, backend

Google allows to preview documents, just open the new tab with address: `https://docs.google.com/gview?url=<urlToFile>&embedded=true`. Where `urlToFile` returns file bytes.

I can't test preview on my local machine, because google can't reach my local instance of the IIS. So right now I should make a new build to the host to make sure that all is working.

Can I provide the access for my local IIS instance for the google so I can test the preview functionality without making a new build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either need to expose a port in your router to your local machine or use a tunnel service such as [ngrok](https://ngrok.com)